# Set alpha on RecyclerView but not selected child (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, alpha

I'm looking for a way to set alpha of all the elements of a RecyclerView without iterating over the elements.

Basically I can set the alpha of the entire recycler and all children will inherit that alpha, but when I update the alpha of the selected child it still inherits the value from its parent instead of updating its own alpha value. All this must happen when the item is clicked which has the following clickListener.

```
// it is the view on which the listener is called that belongs to the recycler
private val click = View.OnClickListener {
   recycler.alpha = 0.2f
   it.alpha = 1f
}
```

I checked that the item is correctly selected and that the clickListener is invoked. Issue seems to be that alpha is inherited from the parent `ViewGroup` but in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View.html#setalpha) I can't find anything about not being able to change an inherited alpha value in a child `view`.

What am I missing? If setting the alpha of the parent `ViewGroup` is a no-go, is there a way to avoid iterating through all the elements and setting the alpha value for each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not inherited - the children are drawn as *part* of the parent.  So by virtue of the entire parent having that alpha, the children are drawn with that alpha.  Setting the alpha on the child to `0.2f` would make that child even *more* transparent.

Your best bet is probably to set the alpha properly in your RecyclerView.Adapter subclass's `onBindViewHolder` method, and change the alpha via changes to the backing data and `notify...` methods.  Trying to change RecyclerView child views outside of the adapter is asking for trouble, because the RecyclerView won't know about them, and might change things on you, add more views, etc.

Comment: "It's not inherited - the children are drawn as part of the parent."
Why is that? I naively thought alpha would be an inherited property "CSS" style.  
The thing is I wanted to avoid saving the alpha in my data and `notify...` because this would require to loop through all the unselected items to update them.  
Guess the best way in this case is to make the view observe a property holding the selected item and render themselves based on if they are selected or not (no multiple item selection).

Comment: "Why is that?" This is just how Android views work.  Observing a property with the selected item could work, as long as you're careful about staying up-to-date with the position (keep in mind, a viewholder may not be re-bound if its position within the dataset changes).

Comment: In the end I did something similar to what explained in [Update recycler view content without refreshing the data](https://medium.com/@MiguelSesma/update-recycler-view-content-without-refreshing-the-data-bb79d768bde8) using live data. To me this is much simpler than `getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition)`